# ASPX page image is not displaying, but size is correct

Tags: asp.net, image

I have an .aspx page that includes an `<img>` tag.  When the page is displayed, the image's size box is correct, so I assume it knows where to find the image; however, no image appears (the "red X box" appears in IE).

Here's the page source (well, the significant parts of it, anyway):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="HeaderImage">
    <!-- "Why is this in a table?"
         So the header text can be centered vertically with the logo -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="/content/images/Header Image.png" alt="Header Image" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2>Main Page</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p />
</body>
</html>
```

Note that if I change the URL of the image source, the image box is only big enough to hold the alt text, so I am assuming that it is able to find the image and get its size.  Why wouldn't the image itself display?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space and see if that works, otherwise verify your path is correct via right clicking on the image or using a browser tool (`F12 Tools` for Internet Explorer, `Firebug` for Firefox or `Chrome Developer Tools`).

Comment: Removing the spaces doesn't work - and when I clear the cache, the original URL stops returning the correct box size until I go to another page that displays the image correctly (so the next time I run the problem page, it knows how big the image should be, but not what's in it).  However, the "working" URL is identical to the "non-working" one, at least according to the Properties box.  Even removing the spaces does not work (and yes, I removed the spaces from the name of the actual image file as well).

Comment: Update: even with the spaces, it appears to work on Firefox - just not in IE8.  I have had a similar problem with IE8, but it was with CMYK-colorspace JPEGs.  Why would a PNG not show up?

Comment: @DonDelGrande - check out [Solving IE7 & IE8 PNG Opacity Problems](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/) for potential issues with PNG files in Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

Er...did I forget to mention that this was in a login page being displayed by forms authentication?

The problem was caused by not having an explicit  tag within a location tag pointing to the folder with the images in it in my web.config file.

(By the way...spaces in the filename had nothing to do with it.)